# Function of special template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a structure template e.g.:

```
template<typename KEY_T, typename VAL_T> 
struct pair
{
    KEY_T key; VAL_T val;
};
```

`VAL_T val` may be the different (string, list or smth else)
What I want is to overload the `operator[]` for the *specified template structure* `pair<std::string, std::list>`, and only for it.
How is it possible?

P.S. I'm writing an Ini-parser and I want to access for settings like `settings[Section][Key]`, where `settings[Section]` returns the `pair<std::string, std::list<Entry>>` and `settings[Section][Key]` then return the string from `std::list<Entry>`

Comment: OT suggestion: avoid names as `pair` that are used for standard classes.

Comment: @max66 - OR just use namespaces. The standard has no right to claim those identifiers in full. That's why they are in namespace std.

Comment: @StoryTeller - yes, but avoiding `using namespace std;` together with `using namespace otherNameSpace` :(

Comment: @max66 - Hardly a sacrifice worth worrying about :)

Comment: Should the primary class template also have some `operator[]`? Or should only `pair<std::string, std::list<Entry>>` specialization have it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class templates may be specialized, either partially:

```
template<typename T> 
struct pair<std::string, std::list<T>>
{
    std::string key;
    std::list<T> val;
    T& operator[](...) {
      //implement
    }
};
```

or fully:

```
template<> 
struct pair<std::string, std::list<Entry>>
{
    std::string key;
    std::list<Entry> val;
    Entry& operator[](...) {
      //implement
    }
};
```

As a side note, consider putting your classes in a designated namespace. Easier to manage if you ever need to work with `std::pair` too.

Comment: As I get it, I can't create a function only, and i have to define the full desired template class again?

Comment: @AlexLarionov - Generally yes. But that may be mitigated. You could for instance define a `pair_base` template as the container of the data. Then your primary `pair` is `struct pair : pair_base<K, V> {};` and the specialization is the same but with the added operator.

Comment: What about explicit specialization of the class template member? It can be used here, as I can see.

Comment: @Constructor - You mean for the full specialization? Yes that may also be done. You should post this as an answer. It might even be just what the OP wants.

Comment: @Constructor - Although that will require the operator declaration (or deleted definition) in the primary class template. Which the OP may not want.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this instead.

```
template <typename KEY, typename VAL>
struct pair
{
    KEY _key;
    VAL _val;
    pair (const KEY& key, const VAL& val):
         _key(key), _val(val)
    {};
    // ... here is the trick
    friend ENTRY& get(pair<std::string, std::list<ENTRY>>& p, size_t idx)
};
ENTRY& get(pair<std::string, std::list<ENTRY>>& p, size_t idx)
{
    return p._val [idx];
};
```

your question is not clear, you said:

`Settings[Section] -> pair <string, list<entry>>;`

`Settings[Section][Key]-> list<entry>;`?? the whole list object??

what you are looking for can be done like this:

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::string>> Settings;
std::string my_value = Settings[Section][Key];
```

`Settings` is a map of maps:

```
[Color] <-- this is the section
pen = blue <-- this is the pair KEY:VALUE
border = green
canvas = black
```